# AsyncSocket set timeout

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, asyncsocket

I am sending data to a local network-device.
If the device is off, a timeout is triggered 75 seconds later. I want to reduce this timeoute by using this code:

```
[sock writeData:self.printData withTimeout:10 tag:1];
```

But the Timeout parameter doesn't change the behavior. Also the special values -1 and 0 seem to have no effect to?

How can I set timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the device is off

Probably you want to look at the connect timeout in that case.

I use the following:

```
[socket connectToHost:host onPort:[port intValue] withTimeout:5 error:&error];
```